# OpenLayers display labels

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, zoom

I am displaying and labelling a polygon Layer using a GeoJSON file and the field nom_comm. I would like to label the polygons between two scales i.e. two zooms.
(So to speak, labels are to be invisible when scale of the map is too high or too little.)

How can I do that?

Sample of HTML:

```
var styleDS = new OpenLayers.Style({
                        'fillOpacity': 0,
                        'strokeColor': "red",
                        'strokeWidth': 0.8,
                        'fontFamily': "Verdana",
                        'fontWeight': "bold",
                        'fontSize': "6.5px",
                        'labelOutlineColor': "white",
                        'labelOutlineWidth': 1,
                        'label': "${getLabel}"/* options */
                                        },
                        {
                        context: { getLabel:function(feature) //affichage nom commune en fonction echelle
                                    { if (map.getZoom() > 9 && map.getZoom() < 12.5) 
                                    { console.log('affiché'); var label = feature.attributes['nom_comm']; 
                                    return label; } 
                                    else { console.log('caché'); return ''; }
                                    } 
                                }  
                            });
```

Then I applied the style like this:

```
var commune = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "commune", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "communes.geojson",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        //autre maniere de creer un style
        styleMap: styleDS, 
        }
);
  map.addLayer(commune);
```

And I don't have a link to the map because it belongs to a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a style with a context :

```
var monstyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    'fillOpacity': 0,
    'strokeColor': "red",
    'strokeWidth': 0.8,
    'label': "${getLabel}",
    'fontFamily': "Verdana",
    'fontWeight': "bold",
    'fontSize': "7px",
    'labelOutlineColor': "white",
    'labelOutlineWidth': 1
}, {
    context: {
        getLabel: function(feature) {
            if (map.zoom > 10 && map.zoom < 13) {
                return feature.attributes.nom_comm;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx.I added this context in styleMap in code above. I got labels "undefined" on the map. Any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe it depends on how your attributes are stored. In my own map I have to return "feature.attributes[scencrue].value". You can try to return "feature.attributes.nom_comm.value" ?

Comment: does not work : same word "undefined" as label everywhere.

Comment: Does it work if you replace map.zoom by map.getZoom() ?

Comment: nope. Labels appear still all the time. (And labels value are always marked as "undefined".)

Comment: This is working for me :
    var styleDS = new OpenLayers.Style({
        label: "${getLabel}"
        /* options */
    }, {context: {
        getLabel: function(feature) {
            if (map.getZoom() > 9 && map.getZoom() < 13) {
                console.log('affiché');
                    var label = feature.attributes[scencrue].value;
                        return label + 'j';
            } else {
                console.log('caché');
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
    });

Do you have a link to your map ?

Comment: Note : If you are using OpenLayers 3 it seems that you have to use **map.getView().getZoom()** instead.

Comment: I am outside of my office. I ll be right back as soon as possible.

Comment: back to my office.

Comment: First post edited

Comment: You can't just paste the code without adapting it to your problem. Take a look at my answer to see how to declare a style. In your recent edition your wrote 'label' twice and kept attributes.scencrue instead of writing the name of your own attribute... It can't work.

Comment: Thanks. Editing and trying again. Until now, I called scripts Openlayers.js and jquery-1.11.1.js. Is it enough ?

Comment: The 'label' should be with the other options and not in a separate part between { }. As long as you see your map, it is enough but there are several versions of Openlayers. If you are using the 3rd version, you can try using map.getView().getZoom() instead of map.getZoom().

Comment: I am only using openlayers2. Working on your code. Thx

Comment: Now it works thanks to your advice. I updated my first post with the code I use. Thx again.